# C# Erro ao Deserializar Json para Objeto

Tags: c#, json, rest, objetos

Estou tomando um erro quando pego o retorno de um serviço REST e tento deserializar para um objeto em C#.

O Serviço REST me retorna a seguinte estrutura(json):

```
{
"Marcacoes_Ponto_Response":
{
    "Item":
    {
        "Codigo_Retorno":"S"
        ,"Mensagem":"Operação realizada com sucesso"
        ,"Numero_Fabricacao_REP":"00099999999999990"
        ,"PIS":"12409663348"
        ,"Data_Marcacao":"20092019"
        ,"Hora_Marcacao":"093715"
    }
}
```

}

No código em C#, uso o seguinte código para deserializar para um objeto:

```
var dadosFuncionario = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultPontoDigitalSAP>(responseFuncionario.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

A definição do objeto usado nos códigos acima segue abaixo:

```
public class ResultPontoDigitalSAP
{
    public List<Marcacoes_Ponto_Response> Marcacoes_Ponto_Response { get; set; }
}

public class Marcacoes_Ponto_Response
{ 
    public string Codigo_Retorno { get; set; }
    public string Mensagem { get; set; }
    public string Numero_Fabricacao_REP { get; set; }
    public string PIS { get; set; }
    public string Data_Marcacao { get; set; }
    public string Hora_Marcacao { get; set; }

}
```

Mas quando o resultado JSON é retornado para aplicação eu tomo um erro do C# de formatação de JSON quando tento deserializar para o objeto definido acima.

Alguém sabe o que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Caro Oscar Filho aqui é português ... pode traduzir a sua pergunta?

Comment: Desculpe, corrigi. Obrigado.

Comment: Se for do jeito que está na pergunta é objeto de objeto e não objeto de array! deve ser isso. Bom se reabrir eu respondo

Comment: @VirgilioNovic reabriu :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O layout desse [json](/questions/tagged/json) é um `objeto` dentro de outro `objeto` e por isso no seu layout da pergunta não bate porque está um `array`, exemplo de como seria:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Marcacoes_Ponto_Response Marcacoes_Ponto_Response { get; set; }
}

public class Marcacoes_Ponto_Response
{
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Codigo_Retorno { get; set; }
    public string Mensagem { get; set; }
    public string Numero_Fabricacao_REP { get; set; }
    public string PIS { get; set; }
    public string Data_Marcacao { get; set; }
    public string Hora_Marcacao { get; set; }
}
```

Usar:

```
string json = responseFuncionario.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var dadosFuncionario = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
```

Comment: Amigo, fiz o teste aqui e o objeto resultante do "Deserialize" continua sendo NULO.

Comment: Você fez alguma errada então ... porque o layout é esse mesmo @OscarFilho . Da uma conferida geralmente o pessoal esquece de colocar algo ...  ou me conte o que você fez agora ou você não fez o exemplo minimo correto isso geralmente acontece aqui ... veja o exemplo é sobre o json que está na pergunta.

Comment: Se você fez um resumo do Json ta ai o problema, é esse JSON mesmo @OscarFilho ?

Comment: Amigo, havia feito confusão! Muito obrigado pela ajuda!! Resolveu meu problema e agora já consigo entender melhor a relação JSON <> OBJETO C#.